# Java capturing telnet output in file

Tags: java, file, telnet, output

I am trying to telnet to a server, run a command and put the output of that command in a file.
I can get the command in the file but not the result of this command.
I cannot see my output on my console either, so I assumed it run but I am not sure.
 Does anybody have any idea?

```
public final static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    FileOutputStream fout = null;

    try
    {
        fout = new FileOutputStream ("spyfile.log");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println(
            "Exception while opening the spy file: "
            + e.getMessage());
    }


    TelnetClient telnet;

    telnet = new TelnetClient();

    try
    {

        telnet.connect("myserver", 23);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    telnet.registerSpyStream(fout);
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream( telnet.getOutputStream() );
    out.println( "mycommand" );     

    try
    {
        telnet.disconnect();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

   fout.close();
    System.exit(0);  
}
```

Comment: Maybe you close telnet connection too early, before it gave any output?

Comment: I don't know since nothing is written to the file, I have no idea what this is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is TelneClient, if this is [Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) class, then you are missing the part that actually reads data exchanged during telnet session. Please run [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/ExampleofuseofTelnetClient.htm) and see how it works, once you get it you'll be able to cut it to your needs.

Comment: Yes I am using commons Net class.  The example you suggested, works but you need to press the carriage return to be able to get the result.  I want to run my telnet command and have the result of this command in a file (or a variable) WITHOUT pressing the carriage return.